# data encryption on amazon Aurora and django system

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am using `amazon aurora` and `django`.

Now, thinking about using [RDS encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)

Hoever while reading documents, a few questions come up to me.

My final goal is encrypting data itself, even mysql root user can not check the data.

1. This doesn't encrypt the database data itself, so if DB user/password is leaked, the data could be stolen?
2. Is there any good way to encrypt the data in database? even root mysql user can not check the data. I am using django, It is enough that only django can encode-decode the data. I should use some django library not database itself? or database has some structure for this purpose?

Comment: You must encrypt data before you write it to your database.

Comment: You mean I need to do this by myself on python without any framework??